# Null exception while calling a database to populate datagrid rows

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, database-connection

so in the following code I *should* be able to connect to a database, and then output that database to a datagrid for the users to view. *However* what is actually happening is that once the code hits the `Load` method, it throws a null error. I'm not sure why, and I would be grateful if you guys could explain why I'm not pulling data correctly...
The line in question is this:

```
List<Users> _users = UserRepository.GetUsers();
```

My code goes as such:

`DBDisplay.xaml.cs`

```
public partial class DBDisplay : Window
{
    public DBDisplay()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        var viewModel = new DbDisplayViewModel();
        viewModel.UserRepository = new UserRepository();
        this.DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

`DBDisplayViewModel.cs`

```
public class DbDisplayViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<Users> _users;

    public IUserRepository UserRepository{ get; set; }

    public DbDisplayViewModel()
    {
        Load();
    }



    public ObservableCollection<Users> Users
    {
        get
        {
            if (_users == null)
            {
                _users = new ObservableCollection<Users>();
            }

            return _users;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                _users = value;
            }
        }
    }

    private void Load()
    {
        List<Users> _users = UserRepository.GetUsers(); // THIS IS THE BROKEN LINE THAT THROWS A NULL ERROR
        Users = new ObservableCollection<Users>(_users);
    }
}
```

`UserRepository.cs`

```
    public class UserRepository : IUserRepository
{
    private string connectionStr;

    public System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection connectionToDB;

    private System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter;

    public void openConnection()
    {
        // create the connection to the database as an instance of System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
        connectionToDB = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionStr);

        //open the connection
        connectionToDB.Open();
    }


    // Get the data set generated by the sqlStatement
    public System.Data.DataSet getDataSet(string sqlStatement)
    {
       dataAdapter = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(sqlStatement, connectionToDB);

        // create the dataset
        var dataSet = new System.Data.DataSet();

        dataAdapter.Fill(dataSet);

        //return the dataSet
        return dataSet;
    }
    public List<Users> GetUsers()
    {
        connectionToDB = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connectionStr);
        connectionToDB.Open();
        List<Users> userlist = new List<Users>();
        DataSet ds = getDataSet("Select UserID, FirstName, LastName from UserData");
        Users users;

        foreach (DataRow row in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            users = new Users
            {
                UserID = row["UserID"].ToString(),
                FirstName = row["FirstName"].ToString(),
                LastName = row["LastName"].ToString()
            };


            userlist.Add(users);
        }

        return userlist;

    }


}
```

`Users.cs` just has some properties
`IUserRepository` has a get set method for User Repository

Comment: With *it throws a null error* you mean a `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: Yes, the extra info is that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `Load` from the constructor. At that time, the `UserRepository` is still `null` (you set it in the call *after* the constructor).

Provide the repository to the constructor and set it from there.

```
public DbDisplayViewModel(IUserRepository repository)
{
    this.UserRepository = repository;

    this.Load();
}
```

Required reading: [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/993547)